# Visual Studio runs part of my C# code twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

This might be hard to explain but I will try my best.  I am working on a project that requires a web app to write to a database.  Currently I am tasked with getting the database queries working.  I have a basic "test" web app in C# with .NET.  In this basic app, in the Startup.cs file, there is a single insert statement I am testing.  Here is the problem: the insert works, but it inserts the piece of data twice.  When I refresh my database, it always comes back with two new entries, with the same data.  I was told by a fellow classmate this might have to do with Visual Studio running the code both on the web app and the "console", but I really have no idea how to change that.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Here is the code for this situation:

```
namespace TimeSlice
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            Console.Write("got here");
            String course = "CS3705";
            int user = 8;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("host;initial catalog = timeslice;user id=timeslice;password=********");
            string query = "Insert into COURSES (courseName, userId) Values ('" + course + "', '" + user + "')";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = con;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.CommandText = query;

            con.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Set a breakpoint on your `ExecuteNonQuery` line and see what happens. 2. **NEVER USE CONCATENATION TO GENERATE SQL** use Parameters instead! 3. Wrap your disable objects in `using()` statements.

Comment: Also, your insert code will run for every request it receives from clients. If the client is a web-browser then note that most browsers make 2 initial requests: one for `/` and the other for `/favicon.ico`. You should add path discrimination to your `Run` callback and/or set-up appropriate routing.

Comment: @Dai But everybody wants to study `', ''); DROP TABLE courses ; -- ` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly then following thing happen.

- When you press F5 or run your application from Browser then it insert statement two times.

If above is the case then following is the reason.

- When your first request comes from Browser like  Chrome or any newer browser then it has two request. Like first for favicon and another for actual Home/Index or something. So It looks like it execute two times.

To avoid that you have to do following thing.

```
app.Run(async context =>
        {
            if( context.Request.Url  == "") // Match with something
            {
            Console.Write("got here");
            String course = "CS3705";
            int user = 8;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("host;initial catalog = timeslice;user id=timeslice;password=********");
            string query = "Insert into COURSES (courseName, userId) Values ('" + course + "', '" + user + "')";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = con;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.CommandText = query;

            con.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
        });
```